# xcode resource-to-copy.txt permission denied

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making an ios app using ionic. When trying to build, xcode gives the following error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRssR.png)

I am not sure how to fix this error. I have tired:

- chmod +x path/to/file
- re-installing cocoa-pods
- updating ionic and Cordova
- removing and adding the platform
- putting sudo in front of the command in copy pods resources in xcode

None of these seem to fix the problem. Is there any solution on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.